# Getting line locations with iText

Tags: itext

How can one find where are lines located in a document with iText?

Suppose say I have a table in a PDF document, and want to read its contents; I would like to find where exactly the cells are located. In order to do that I thought I might find the intersections of lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your only option using iText will be to parse the PDF tokens manually. Before doing that I would [have a copy of the PDF spec handy](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

*(I'm a .Net guy so I use iTextSharp but other than some capitalization differences and property declarations they're almost 100% the same.)*

You can get the individual tokens using the `PRTokeniser` object which you feed bytes into from calling `getPageContent(pageNum)` on your `PdfReader`.

```
//Get bytes for page 1
byte[] pageBytes = reader.getPageContent(1);
//Get the tokens for page 1
PRTokeniser tokeniser = new PRTokeniser(pageBytes);
```

Then just loop through the `PRTokeniser`:

```
PRTokeniser.TokType tokenType;
string tokenValue;

while (tokeniser.nextToken()) {
    tokenType = tokeniser.tokenType;
    tokenValue = tokeniser.stringValue;
    //...check tokenValue, do something with it
}
```

As far a `tokenValue`, you'd want to probably look for `re` and `l` values for rectangle and line. If you see an `re` then you want to look at the ***previous*** 4 values and if you see an `l` then ***previous*** 2 values. This also means that you need to store each `tokenValue` in an array so you can look back later.

Depending on what you used to create the PDF with you might get some interesting results. For instance, I created a 4 cell table with Microsoft Word and saved as a PDF. For some reason there are two sets of 10 rectangles with many duplicates, but the general idea still works.

Below is C# code targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0. You should be able to convert it to Java and iText very easily, I noted the one line that has .Net-specific code that needs to be adjusted from a Generic List (`List<string>`) to a Java equivalent, probably an `ArrayList`. You'll also need to adjust some casing, .Net uses `Object.Method()` whereas Java uses `Object.method()`. Lastly, .Net accesses properties without gets and sets, so `Object.Property` is both the getter and setter compared to Java's `Object.getProperty` and `Object.setProperty`.

Hopefully this gets you started at least!

```
        //Source file to read from
        string sourceFile = "c:\\Hello.pdf";

        //Bind a reader to our PDF
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);

        //Create our buffer for previous token values. For Java users, List<string> is a generic list, probably most similar to an ArrayList
        List<string> buf = new List<string>();

        //Get the raw bytes for the page
        byte[]  pageBytes = reader.GetPageContent(1);
        //Get the raw tokens from the bytes
        PRTokeniser tokeniser = new PRTokeniser(pageBytes);

        //Create some variables to set later
        PRTokeniser.TokType tokenType;
        string tokenValue;

        //Loop through each token
        while (tokeniser.NextToken()) {
            //Get the types and value
            tokenType = tokeniser.TokenType;
            tokenValue = tokeniser.StringValue;
            //If the type is a numeric type
            if (tokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.NUMBER) {
                //Store it in our buffer for later user
                buf.Add(tokenValue);
            //Otherwise we only care about raw commands which are categorized as "OTHER"
            } else if (tokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.OTHER) {
                //Look for a rectangle token
                if (tokenValue == "re") {
                    //Sanity check, make sure we have enough items in the buffer
                    if (buf.Count < 4) throw new Exception("Not enough elements in buffer for a rectangle");
                    //Read and convert the values
                    float x = float.Parse(buf[buf.Count - 4]);
                    float y = float.Parse(buf[buf.Count - 3]);
                    float w = float.Parse(buf[buf.Count - 2]);
                    float h = float.Parse(buf[buf.Count - 1]);
                    //..do something with them here
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The link to the PDF Spec in the answer is no longer valid. You can try this URL. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: In iTextSharp 5.5, you need a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` to instantiate PRTokeniser: `PRTokeniser tokeniser = new PRTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pageBytes));`